# char *cQuery append string

Tags: c, string

I have a String and I declared it as

```
char *cQuery = "My Name Is ";
```

and I want to append another string. In objective-c, I'd say stringByAppendingString:newString

I'm a little rusty with C being used in Objective-C classes. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) method from string.h but must be mindful that the destination string must be of sufficient size to hold the newly combined strings.

```
char destination[100];
char *cQuery = "My Name Is ";
char *anotherStr = "Peter";

strcpy(destination, cQuery);
strcat(destination, anotherStr);
```

Comment: This is good but we don't know the size of the string. So we can't assume its 100 length.

Answer (score 3):

By declaring the string like so, you are declaring cQuery to be a constant string.

```
// You can change cQuery using strcat, snprintf etc.
char *cQuery = "My Name Is ";

// Error! Cannot do this.
// strcat(cQuery, "John");
```

If you want cQuery to be modifiable, you will need to create a char array with an explicit size, then copy over the starting contents into that string.

```
char cQuery[128];

// use snprintf or strcpy to initialize
strcpy(cQuery, "My name is ");

// now you can modify cQuery by calling strcat.
strcat(cQuery, "Funny Name");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use snprintf. (It's one of my favorite functions!)

Like this:

```
void add_it(const char *name)
{
    char buffer[256];
    const size_t buffer_len = sizeof(buffer);

    snprintf(buffer, buffer_len, "My Name Is %s", name);
    do_something(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `strcat` see help [here](http://www.dfstermole.net/OAC/hstrings.html#strcat)

Comment: I did that and I get Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: @Cocoa Dev: You cannot append to a string literal. "My Name Is " is a string literal and is stored in read-only memory.